# CSS align text so its in straight line

Tags: css

I have split the page in 3 sections

- 25% width
- 50% width
- 25% width

How can i get my menu in straight line after using `text-align:right`. I don't want to use `margin-left` cause without using it the web is more responsive to other devices and looks more appealing.

What i expect to get - [Imagur Image of expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWd6O.jpg).
I want menu to start at yellow line.

My current code in JSFiddle - [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Krichukz/475sdf9w/13/)

Comment: Why are you using a `table` and manually building a grid when you're including Bootstrap?

Comment: @APAD1 Took this as an example [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h)c

Comment: You need to update your question to include a [mcve]; a link to a third party site is insufficient. If the third party site is down, blocked, or otherwise inaccessible then this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be using Bootstrap, you might as well just use the existing grid system that comes with it. In order to left align an element with right aligned text, you can simply float it:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:right;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Firstname</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add this css code:

```
.first ul{
  text-align:left;
}
```

Your code would become:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.first{
width:25%;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
text-align:right;
}
.first ul{
  text-align:left;
}
.table{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.three{
width:25%;
float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="main">

<div class="first">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Firstname</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<div class="three">
<p>
test</p>
</p>

</div>

</div>
```

I hope it helps.